# Constructing a "limit" function. But is it measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measurable-functions

Let $\alpha_n:\,(0,T)\rightarrow A$, where $A\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ compact, a sequence of measurable functions. Since $A$ is compact, for almost every $t\in (0,T)$, there exists a subsequence $\alpha_{n_k}(t)$ and $\alpha_t\in A$ such that $\alpha_{n_k}(t)\rightarrow \alpha_t$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$.
Now, we define $\alpha:(0,T)\rightarrow A$ via:
\begin{align*}
\alpha(t):=\alpha_t.
\end{align*}
Is $\alpha$ also measurable?

Thank You in advance!

Comment: You are using $n$ in two different ways.

Comment: I don't see this. For every $t$ $\alpha_n(t)$ defines a sequence in $A$. Hence, it has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: But we're in $\mathbb R^n.$

Comment: You are right. I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

The limit superior of a sequence of measurable functions is measurable (e.g. see Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis Thm 1.14.).
In your case, $a$ is the limit (and hence the limit superior) of the sequence of measurable functions $a_{n_k}$, hence measurable.

Comment: We only know that for each $t$ there exists a subsequence $\alpha_{n_k}(t)$ which is convergent (the $k$ is dependet on $t$). At least for me, it is not clear that this implies the existence of a subsequence $\alpha_{n_k}$ which converges almost everwhere to $\alpha$.